# To create bottle neck by extruding outwards all faces normally?

Tags: extrude

I want the portion of the bottle as shown by red arrows in the image.
So I need to do something like extrusion but how to extrude it towards the center and away from the center?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extrude along vertex normals to do that. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then 'Region (vertex normals)'

[image]

**edit** if previous version does not has this extrusion mode:

- Remove the ring, for instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd>
- Extrude and scale and only on X and Y: <kbd>E</kbd> (extrude) <kbd>s</kbd> (scale) and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (only along X and Y)
- Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, bridge the loop

[image]

Comment: But in my blender version 2.69 I don't see this option after pressing ALT+E, I see only Edges only and Vertices only

Comment: @PrashantTomar, I'm not sure to remember for this version, but after the selection, have a look in the menus on bottom instead of the shortcut